# Inserting values from 1 table to another error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm Having 2 tables

```
modules_templates
```

and

```
templates
```

In table templates i have 75 records . I want to insert into table modules_templates some data which template_id in modules_templates = template_id from templates.
I created this query :

```
INSERT INTO `modules_templates` (`module_template_id`,`module_template_modified`,`module_id`,`template_id`) VALUES  ('','2014-04-14 10:07:03','300',(SELECT template_id FROM templates WHERE 1))
```

And I'm having error that `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row` , how to add all 75 rows in 1 query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT 
    INTO `modules_templates` 
    (`module_template_id`,`module_template_modified`,`module_id`,`template_id`) 

    (SELECT '','2014-04-14 10:07:03','300',template_id FROM templates WHERE 1)
```

Your query didn't work because you were inserting value for one row, where last field i.e result of sub query was multirow, so what you had to do was to put those single row values in sub-query so they are returned for each row in sub query.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT '','2014-04-14 10:07:03','300',template_id FROM templates WHERE 1)' at line 5 . 
But i want to add all 75 rows with 1 subquery , is that even possible ?

Comment: @woj_jas remove `values` keyword and then execute

Comment: @woj_jas yes this query is inserting all rows with one sub query

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `modules_templates`
(`module_template_id`,`module_template_modified`,`module_id`,`template_id`) 
SELECT '','2014-04-14 10:07:03','300',template_id FROM templates WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `modules_templates`
(`module_template_id`,`module_template_modified`,`module_id`,`template_id`) 
VALUES  
('','2014-04-14 10:07:03','300',
     (SELECT template_id FROM templates WHERE 1 limit 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

To add more than one row, the field count/type must match :

```
INSERT INTO foo SELECT * FROM bar;
```

Please see the following link on how to do this properly :

[http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql%5finsert%5finto%5fselect.asp)